# uses of container_of and dev_set_drvdata and dev_get_drvdata

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

I am new to device drivers and I was learning this container_of and dev_get_drvdata and came across this driver.I removed some partof this driver so as to make it compact.

```
    static void tsl4531_polling_worker(struct work_struct *work)
    {

        u8 buf[2];

        struct tsl4531_data *data   = container_of(to_delayed_work(work),
                            struct tsl4531_data, work);

        mutex_lock(&data->update_lock);
        buf[0] = DEVICE_LIGHT;
        buf[1] = GET_REQUEST;
        sam4l_send_request(data->pdata.sam4l,2,buf);
        mutex_unlock(&data->update_lock);

    }

    static ssize_t store_enable_value(struct device *dev,struct device_attribute *devattr,const char *buf,size_t count){

        struct tsl4531_data *data = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

        if((buf[0] == '1') && (!tsl4531_enabled)) {
            schedule_delayed_work(&data->work, msecs_to_jiffies(50));
            tsl4531_enabled = 1;

        } else if (buf[0] == '0'){
            tsl4531_enabled = 0;
            cancel_delayed_work_sync(&data->work);
            tsl4531_lux = 0;

        }

        return count;
    }

    static DEVICE_ATTR(enable,S_IRUGO | S_IWUGO,
               show_enable_value, store_enable_value );        

    static struct attribute *tsl4531_attributes[] = {
        &dev_attr_lux_show.attr,
        &dev_attr_enable.attr,
        NULL
    };

    static const struct attribute_group tsl4531_attr_group = {
        .attrs = tsl4531_attributes,
    };

    void tsl4531_callback_fun(struct work_struct *work)
    {

        struct tsl4531_data *chip = container_of(work,struct tsl4531_data,
                    pdata.work.work);

        tsl4531_lux = chip->pdata.response[2];//Need to check on which response index we get lux value

        input_report_abs(tsl4531_dev, ABS_X,tsl4531_lux);
        input_sync(tsl4531_dev);
        schedule_delayed_work(&chip->work, msecs_to_jiffies(1500));

    }

    static int __devinit tsl4531_probe(struct platform_device *pdev){
        struct tsl4531_data *chip;  
        int err=0;

        chip = kzalloc(sizeof(struct tsl4531_data), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!chip){
            dev_dbg(&pdev->dev, "memory not allocated for tsl4531 light sensor module.\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
        }

        dev_set_drvdata(&pdev->dev,chip);//here we give address in chip to struct device

        tsl4531_dev=input_allocate_device();
        if(!tsl4531_dev) {
            dev_dbg(&pdev->dev, "memory not allocated for tsl4531_dev.\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
        }

        err=input_register_device(tsl4531_dev);
        if(err){
            dev_dbg(&pdev->dev, "input register poll the device failed ... \n");
            goto err_reg_poll;
        }

        mutex_init(&chip->update_lock);

        err = sysfs_create_group(&pdev->dev.kobj,&tsl4531_attr_group);
        if (err){
            dev_dbg(&pdev->dev, "creating sysfs group for tsl4531 sensor module failed.\n");
            goto exit_err;
        }

        INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&chip->work, tsl4531_polling_worker);
        INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&chip->pdata.work,tsl4531_callback_fun);

        chip->pdata.dev_id = DEVICE_LIGHT;

        return 0;

        return err;
    }

    static int __devexit tsl4531_remove(struct platform_device *pdev){

        struct tsl4531_data *data = dev_get_drvdata(&pdev->dev);

        cancel_delayed_work_sync(&data->work);
        cancel_delayed_work(&data->pdata.work);
        sysfs_remove_group(&pdev->dev.kobj, &tsl4531_attr_group);
        unregister_sam4l_client(&data->pdata);
        kfree(data);
        return 0;
    }

    static const struct platform_device_id tsl4531_id[] = {
        { "tsl45317", 0 },
        { }
    };

    static struct platform_driver tsl4531_driver = {
        .driver = {
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .name  = "tsl45317",
        },
        .probe      = tsl4531_probe,
        .remove     = tsl4531_remove,
        .suspend    = tsl4531_suspend,
        .resume     = tsl4531_resume,
        .id_table   = tsl4531_id,
    };


    static int __init tsl4531_init(void){

        return platform_driver_register(&tsl4531_driver);
    }


    static void __exit tsl4531_exit(void){

        platform_driver_unregister(&tsl4531_driver);
    }
```

I have few doubts regarding working of container_of and dev_get_drvdata

1)in the polling_worker function we can see one container_of macro which fetches the address to the original structure and assigned to struct tsl4531_data *data;
2)in the probe function we can see one call to dev_set_drvdata and in store_enable_value and tsl4531 dev_get_drvdata.

Isn't both container_of and dev_set and dev_get doing same things here?

Answer (score 1):

`container_of` and `dev_set, dev_get` are different. But yes, the intention might be the same. Both are actually used to retrieve the pointer (usually to the private data structure of the device).

`container_of()` actually does a reverse mapping. It does the opposite of `&struct_base->member` operation. In the previous operation you have the pointer to the base of the structure and need the address of one of its member. While, `container_of` takes in the address of the member and returns the base address. In the `tsl4531_polling_worker()` function, it has the member's address and using `container_of` it is getting the base address of the structure (`struct tsl4531_data`)

`dev_set_drvdata()` is generally used to preserve a pointer's address, such that it could be retrieved later using `dev_get_drvdata()`. Unlike reverse mapping, the functions stores and loads the address from a pointer of type `void *` (refer http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L595)